# Add folder of images to onefile exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

My application using images from a folder "Images"  I access these images throughout my application and I would like to add it to my onefile exe.  Problem is when I try to run my file it errors out unless I add the Images folder to the same location as the exe so I know its not adding it right.
I believe it may be with the way I have the destination.

Here is how I currently get the images in my app.

```
tkinter.PhotoImage(file =  "./Images/btnOK.png")
```

Here is how im generating my exe

```
 pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data C:/Users/Paul_Program_Machine/Documents/Python_Code/GuiTests/Images/*'; 'Images" myapp.py
```

**EDIT:** Spec File

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['myapp.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Paul_Program_Machine\\Documents\\Python_Code\\GuiTests'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\Paul_Program_Machine\\Documents\\Python_Code\\GuiTests\\Images\\*', 'Images')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='myapp',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

Its actually coming up the path were the EXE file is and looking for the actual Images folder.  I want it to actually pull the images from the EXE.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you try to access a file using `.`, you're trying to do that based on your *current working directory* (which can be, for example, the directory the terminal is inside). However, when you use Pyinstaller, your code loses the reference and can't access the correct directory. [The documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is far more extensive on this topic.

In programming, using relative paths could not be a good idea. If you're using Pyinstaller, it's a *terrible* idea. You would want to use the constant `__file__` to check the actual file location, [but it'll also not work](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file).

The way I do that works both unpacked and packed with Pyinstaller is the following:

```py
import os
# __DIR__ contains the actual directory that this file is in.
__DIR__ = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

# ...

# Now you can access your image this way (and it will work on all platforms ):
tkinter.PhotoImage(file =  os.path.join(__DIR__, "Images", "btnOK.png"))
```

- The `__DIR__` stuff isn't magic! It comes from [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file).
- `os.path.join` will produce an OS-aware path, so `os.path.join("a", "b")` would produce `a/b` on Linux/Mac and `a\b` on Windows, so use this or [`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) where you can.

And, finally, a hint. You don't need to repeat the entire `pyinstaller` command (which can be very long) every time. Once you have your `myapp.spec`, you can just do `pyinstaller myapp.spec -y` (`-y` skips confirmation message about overwrite `dist/`) and you're done.

Comment: First, thanks for the very detailed response.  Being new at all this I think my biggest issue is knowing what to enter in for the search.  So I end up wasting most my time.  You took the time to help and give me great location of resources to help me understand it even further.  So, many thanks to you.  I have made all the changes but I think I'm missing something because now it won't run even if I add the images file to the directory.  Maybe it has something to do with my --add -data line?

Comment: It appears its still looking for the images in the 'Images' folder in the current DIR rather than the EXE

Comment: Can you add your `myapp.spec`? Maybe it's the slash (in Windows it should be `\\ ` rather than `/`), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ok i added the spec file above.

Comment: Is there a quick fix to this? My code has a billion of these lines which get images from an "Assests" folder in the same dir. I can't just go and change each and everyone. Is there any other way ? Thanks